# 'undefined property of undefined' error while trying to toggle control's disabled property

Tags: javascript

I have a C# web application that uses Razor views and Kendo UI web controls. On my form, I have a DropDownList defined like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.MentalStatus).HtmlAttributes(new { id = "cmbMentalStatus", @class = "k-dropdown-width-30", @tabIndex = "1", style = "width:60px", onchange = "OnChangeC0100(cmbMentalStatus);" }).BindTo(ViewBag.ZeroToOne).OptionLabel(" "))
```

The `onchange` property refers to this JS method:

```
function OnChangeC0100(cmb)
{
    var stupidJS = document.getElementById("cmbV14_Adm_C0200_RepetitionThreeWords_Tab6");

    stupidJS.disabled = (cmb.options[cmb.selectedIndex].value == "0");
}
```

When the second line tries to execute, I get this error

> "Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined"

What am I doing incorrectly? If I set a breakpoint, `cmb` is not `null`. `stupidJS` is not `null`.

Per [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp), `disabled` is the property to set. Is that not accurate?

Edit: I've looked at these questions:

[How to Get Dropdown's Selected Item's text in Kendo UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600895/how-to-get-dropdowns-selected-items-text-in-kendo-ui)

[how to get selected value for Kendo DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702982/how-to-get-selected-value-for-kendo-dropdownlist)

http://www.telerik.com/forums/dropdownlist-getting-clientside-value-on-selected-item-in-mvc

and the documentation here; http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/api

But no matter what I try in the Watch window, I can't get it to work:

[image]

That first one is the closest; at least it returns a value, but it's not the correct one. I selected the item whose text and value are both "1", yet it gives an empty string. Not shown in the screenshot, but `$("#cmb").kendoDropDownList().val()` gives `undefined`. Why is that if I hardcode a reference to the control, it sort-of works, yet the object passed as a parameter to the method doesn't work?

Comment: _"`cmb` is not `null`"_, what is it though?  the error indicates it's probably something to do with that rather than `stupidJS.disabled` - it's reading a property, and it's reporting `undefined` for both the name of the property it's trying to read (`cmb.selectedIndex`) and the object it's trying to read it on (`cmb.options`), indicating that `cmb` doesn't have either of those properties.  It _looks_ like it should be your `<select>`, but you need to debug it to ensure it's what you think it is.

Comment: @JamesThorpe `cmb` is the control created in my razor snippet at the beginning of my post. And from [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) that's how I determined that's how you access the drop down list's selected item

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution to my *actual* task:

```
function OnChangeC0100(cmb)
{
    var cmbVal = $("#" + cmb.id).val();
    var enabled = (cmbVal != "0");

    $("#cmbSomeControl").kendoDropDownList({ enable: enabled });
    $("#cmbSomeOtherControl").kendoDropDownList({ enable: enabled });

    if (cmbVal == "0")
        document.getElementById("cmbV14_Adm_C900A_MemoryRecall_Season_Tab6").focus();
}
```

And I modified my kendo DropDownList to pass `this` to the method, rather than the string containing the ID.